# SwiftUI FocusState not working in SwiftUI. keyboard not toggle

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, preview

Here is my code. It not working and the keyboard inn't toggle as expected.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FocusStateBC_: View {
    
    @FocusState private var usernaminFocus : Bool 
    @State private var username : String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Your name here...", text: $username)
                .focused($usernaminFocus)
                .padding(.leading)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.gray.brightness(0.3))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            Button("TOOGLE FOCUS STATE"){
                usernaminFocus.toggle()
            }
            
        }.padding(40)
    }
}

struct FocusStateBC__Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FocusStateBC_()
    }
}
```

Keyboard toggle after click button below textfield

Comment: I can't get `@FocusState` to change no matter what I do... tried everything, also in a plain skeleton project with basically nothing but a TextField.